# Determining the Inverse in a Set with a Binary Operation

Tags: group-theory

How can I find the inverse of an element in this set under the proposed group  multiplication operation. 
$G = \{a + b\omega : \omega^3 = 1,\: $a$\:\text{and}\:b\:\text{not both}\:0\:\text{at the same time}\}.$

How can I show that $G$ is a group under multiplication.

Comment: Why not use $\omega$ to represent omega?

Comment: yes, sorry was my mistake its  ω3

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ integers?

Comment: a and b are real numbers but can not be 0 at a same time

Comment: Compute $(a+b\omega)(c+d\omega)$ and use $\omega^2=-1-\omega$. Then order by real part and $\omega$-part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* To solve $(a+b\omega)(x+y\omega)=1$, expand and simplify to get a linear system for $x,y$.

(I assume that $G$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$ and that $\omega\ne1$. Then 
$\omega^3=1$ implies $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$.)

*Solution:*

> $1 + 0 \omega= (a+b\omega)(x+y\omega) = (ax-by)+(bx+(a-b)y)\omega$ gives $ax-by=1$, $bx+(a-b)y)=0$, and $x = \dfrac{a - b}{d}$, $y = -\dfrac{b}{d}$, for $d=a^2 - a b + b^2$.

Comment: will you please explain... I am not able to find this...

Comment: @MinaxiJoshi, have you followed the hint?

Comment: yes.. this is what I have tried

Comment: yes.. this is what I have tried

(a+bω)(c+dω) = 1
c+dω = 1/(a+bω)

by simplifying this I got following

c+dω = a-bω/( a^2 + b^2 + b^2ω)

so now how can I separate this equation to convert it into a+bω form..?